# how to get formatted data(by wmd editor) in textarea

Tags: php, wmd-editor, wmd-markdown

I want to show the data or about us to edit like stackoverflow so i used wmd editor i also used the markdown.php for markdown and its working fine. but when i fetch data in text area to show in wmd editor for that i am doing

```
 <textarea id="wmd-input"  class="wmd-panel" name="aboutme" value=""><?php echo $users->aboutme();?></textarea>
```

now the problem is that i am getting the data form `$users->aboutme()` is with html tag

[image]

here i want to know how to remove the html tag and show like when i cal outside the textarea

Comment: Are you sure you covered all the "dumb" things like correctly include javascript and css files or assigning proper class name or something like that?

Comment: @MichelKogan ya sir,i have done correctly and all are working properly

Comment: You need to echo the original markdown code therein. not the HTML code. Don't you store the markdown?

Comment: @hakre ya sir, i have stored marked down but how to echo original markdown code?

Comment: Well it's normally a string and you just echo it. So I'm a bit puzzeled why you ask I must admit.

Comment: @hakre sir,the string showed in wmd editor is stored same in the database  and i echoed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
<?php echo htmlentities($users->aboutme());?>
```